# Paypal on iOS app

Tags: ios, paypal

I am developing a simple iOS app which receive payment from Paypal and send physical goods to customer. I learnt from www.x.com that I need to submit my app to Paypal for approval.

Recently Paypal is moving from x.com to developer.paypal.com and released new version iOS sdk, however there is no mention about app submission and approval procedure on new developer site. I have several questions:

1. Is it still need to submit my app to Paypal for approval? How?
2. Is Paypal iOS SDK only works in US because live credentials only available in US? (In x.com seems there is no mention about this restriction)
3. If my app need to be submitted to x.com, where can I get the Paypal Device's UDID?
4. I am now using PayPal Mobile Express Checkout Library (PP_MECL) 1.03, is this version still working? Or I need to move to 1.04? Seems PayPal iOS SDK 1.04 is a totally different thing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you use the new iOS SDK you don't need to submit your app for approval.
 If the iOS SDK has the functionality you need you should use it over MECL - it has a much slicker interface and supports credit card payments. 
The FAQs https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/support/faq mention that the iOS SDK is only targeted for US market at this time.

Comment: Thanks! Because my app is targeted on Hong Kong market, I think I need to stay at ver 1.03 SDK. BTW, where can i find Paypal Device UDID on PayPal official site? Seems all UDID found on Google are come from third party site.

Answer (score 1):

if you're just using the MECL library, you do not have to submit the app for approval, you just need the dev and production token you automatically get from their portal once you add your application definition to www.x.com.

This token must be used in your code when you set the ENV_LIVE environment.

For iOS, the latest MECL version is 1.0.3, but make sure you really have the latest package, because they released an update for iOS 6 in december 2012 without changing the library version numbers (gasp!)

As others have already pointed out, the new PayPal iOS SDK 1.04 is a completely different library, but if you're accepting payments on your mobile website, the MECL library is still the right option.

Cheers

Comment: I have follow the same path but at the end I get the empty token. how can I solved it ?